# Plotting Many Colorful Rectangles

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I have data that I'd like to plot. I think the best way to do this is with a series of rectangles. I'd like each rectangle to span a width delta_t (each time interval is the same) and a height delta_f (the frequency intervals may differ) and each rectangle's color is given by the log(z). [This example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/statistics/errorbars_and_boxes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-errorbars-and-boxes-py) seems to have some hints, but I'm not able to put it all together. Here's what I've gotten so far

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

def make_rectangle(t_min, f_min, delta_t, delta_f, z):
    return Rectangle(xy = (t_min, f_min), width = delta_t, height = delta_f, edgecolor = 'k')

timeex=[0,1,2,3,4]
frequencyex=[0,.1,1,10,100]
zex=[[1,1.2,1.1,1.5,1.6], [.01,120,.11,1.6,1.5], 
[.1,.12,1.1e-6,15,16], [1,1.2,1.1,1.5,1.6], [.01,120,.11,1.6,1.5]]

tiles = []

for i in range(len(timeex) - 1):
    t_min = timeex[i]
    f_min = frequencyex[i]
    t_max = timeex[i + 1]
    f_max = frequencyex[i + 1]
    for j in range(len(zex[i])):
        rect = make_rectangle(t_min, f_min, t_max - t_min, f_max - f_min, zex[i][j])
        tiles.append(rect)
        
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)        
p = PatchCollection(tiles, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
ax.add_collection(p)
fig.colorbar(p)
fig.show()
```

This produces the attached image. This plot is lacking in a few ways: the rectangle heights aren't what I would expect. Logscaleing the axis doesm't help. I don't know how to logarithmically color the rectangeles. I'd like to normalize the colorscale between something like 10e-6 and 10.

The end product I'm envisioning looks somewhat like the outputs shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-colors-from_levels_and_colors-in-python/).

I'm using Python 3.6 and matplotlib 3.3.2.

[image: A misbehaving plot.]

Edit: the fantastic answer below solved most of my graphing problems. I turned myself around with the loops, but I sorted that out quickly. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Something strange in the code is `for j in range(len(zex[i])):` which each time creates 5 rectangles with a different color but on exactly the same xy,width,height position. Another problem is that the smallest frequency is zero, which is at infinity on a log-scale.

Comment: @JohanC Regarding the log-scale, one solution is to switch from `ax.set_yscale("log")` to `ax.set_yscale("symlog", linthresh=<whatever power of 10>)` so that the area between the threshold and 0 is considered linear and avoids any log(0) issue. One problem is that the threshold is hard to determine automatically to get something that looks nice. I would use the top y of the lowest rectangle for example. https://i.imgur.com/ThAFKWv.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that I added or changed to obtain this:

[image]

- changed the y-axis scale to log.
- manually changed the x- and y-limits so that the rectangles would fit.
- specified a `norm` for your `PatchCollection` so that it knows how to turn values into colors. Without this, you can only use the 0-1 range which is not what you want.
- specified the `array` of your `PatchCollection` so that it knows **which** values to turn into colors. We store the list of provided `zex[i][j]` values for this purpose. No need to provide those values  to `make_rectangle` (they were unused anyway).

In theory you could calculate automatically the min and max values of the norm as well as the limits of the ax from the data. Here I went with the norm you gave in the OP (1e-6, 10) and manual limits.

```py
# Imports.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np

def make_rectangle(t_min, f_min, delta_t, delta_f):
    return Rectangle(xy = (t_min, f_min), width = delta_t, height = delta_f, edgecolor = 'k')

timeex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
frequencyex = [0, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
zex = [[1, 1.2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.6],
       [0.01, 120, 0.11, 1.6, 1.5], 
       [0.1, 0.12, 1.1e-6, 15, 16],
       [1, 1.2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.6],
       [0.01, 120, 0.11, 1.6, 1.5]]

tiles = []
values = []
for i in range(len(timeex) - 1):
    t_min = timeex[i]
    f_min = frequencyex[i]
    t_max = timeex[i + 1]
    f_max = frequencyex[i + 1]
    for j in range(len(zex[i])):
        rect = make_rectangle(t_min, f_min, t_max - t_min, f_max - f_min)
        tiles.append(rect)
        values.append(zex[i][j])
        
# Create figure and ax.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    

# Normalize entry values to 0-1 for the colormap, and add the colorbar.
norm = LogNorm(vmin=1e-6, vmax=10)
p = PatchCollection(tiles, cmap=plt.cm.jet, norm=norm, match_original=True) # You need `match_original=True` otherwise you lose the black edgecolor.
fig.colorbar(p)
ax.add_collection(p)

# Set the "array" of the patch collection which is in turn used to give the appropriate colors.
p.set_array(np.array(values))

# Scale the axis so that the rectangles show properly. This can be done automatically
# from the data of the patches but I leave this to you.
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_xlim(0, 8)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Nice.  I was under the impression that the `zex` values were meant to determine the logscale color. Otherwise, they seem quite dummy. (That would mean `values.append(zex[i][j])` instead of `values.append(f_max - f_min)`, it's just a detail in your code.)

Comment: My idea for `xlim` would be something like `ax.set_xlim(timeex[0]-0.2, timeex[-1]+0.2)`. Adding a margin to the `ylim` would be trickier, especially for the lower limit.  Again, just a minor detail.